# ImportError: No module named psycopg2._psycopg with google appengine

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

I used [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql-postgres) from Google to connect my postgres instance to my application.
Google indicates that psycopg2 is supported.

But here is my error:

```
File "/Users/Personal-Project/app/lib/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
File "/Users/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1093, in load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named psycopg2._psycopg
```

Here is my requirements.txt :

```
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
psycopg2==2.7.4
```

In my psycopg2 folder, I have a _psycopg.so file.
I used python 2.7 and coding on Mac OS.

Comment: Are you running standard or flexible env?  It looks like your are running in the standard sandboxed environment, which [doesn't permit c extensions (or .so files)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)

Comment: I'm running in standard env, so try to move to flexible

Comment: @snakecharmerb maybe you can post your comment as answer. Don't you think?

Comment: Has this been resolved? I have been struggling to use the same psycopg driver i use locally in the app engine for sometime.